# Spring schedule task not working when setting it with a specific day of the month (@IsCronTabSchedule)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to schedule a task that runs every month on the 9th day at 11 AM.

I use this expression: "0 0 9 08 * *" but it not working.

But when I use "0 0 9 * * *". Then it runs at 9 AM every day.

Comment: I did not test but I would have written it as "0 11 9 * ?"

Comment: @GaëlMarziou It requires 6 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It should be "0 0 11 9 * ?"

- `0 0 11` means 11:00:00 AM
- `9` is the day of the month
- `*` any month
- `?` any day of the week, could probably be also `*`

Official docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html